# Making an object non-callable

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, functions are callable.

Can I remove this attribute from a function, leaving only a normal object?

```
var foo = function () {};
foo.[[callable]] = false; // pseudocode
foo(); // "foo is not a function"
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you looking to do that couldn't be done with a plain old object?

Comment: @user3749178 Curiosity.

Comment: You might have to dig into an implementation like V8 to see how it determines if it's a function object or a regular object. I've never seen this distinction documented. If `typeof(foo)` returns `'function'` it's presumed to be callable, and I'm pretty sure you can't change the type of an existing object.

Comment: It's part of ES6 to be able to [subclass Function](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-function-constructor) though I don't think that'll let you make it not callable.

Comment: In order to answer your question, I need a better understanding of the expected usage

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can I remove this attribute from a function, leaving only a normal object?

No. Functions (the evaluation behaviour, not their object properties) are pretty much immutable.

The [*callability*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-iscallable) of objects is determined by whether they have a `[[call]]` slot. The [spec says about those](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots):

> *Internal slots are allocated as part of the process of creating an object and may not be dynamically added to an object.*

(and it is implied that they cannot dynamically be removed either). Furthermore, "*These internal methods are not part of the ECMAScript language*" and "*are no object properties*", which means they cannot be accessed, set, deleted or manipulated in any imaginable way by the means of the language.

`[[call]]` slots are part of various objects, where they always contain an internal method, but they are never mutated except for their initialisation (once). They come in various kinds:

- [`[[call]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) of user-defined function objects, initialised in step 8 of [`FunctionAllocate`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-functionallocate)
- [`[[call]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-built-in-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) of builtin function objects, initialised implicitly by the environment
- [`[[call]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) of bound function objects, initialised in step 6 of [`BoundFunctionCreate`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-boundfunctioncreate)
- [`[[call]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-call-thisargument-argumentslist) of some proxy objects, initialised conditionally in step 7a of [`ProxyCreate`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-proxycreate) iff the proxy target is callable as well

As you can see, there is no way to alter or even remove the `[[call]]` slot of an object, not even on proxies. Your best bet is

- make the function `throw` when called in an inopportune state
- create a new, uncallable object from the function by means of

  ```
  var obj = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(fn)), fn);
  ```

Comment: Wow, those 125 rep came in quick :-)

Comment: You answered the question! Unlike the 100 other people who viewed it, and the three downvoters.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't.

The functions have a property called `call()` which calls the body of the function (sorry for the redundancy).

You can set this property to any expression like for example

```
foo.call = console.log('foo not a function');
```

but that will not prevent the function's body to be called.

And since you cannot set it to a function, you can't use the `event.preventDefault()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I like providing an additional point of view to what [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) already [did mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680473/making-an-object-non-callable/29798915#29798915), also encouraged by this answer within the OP's question.

> For what purpose? –  user3749178 Apr 16 at 16:18

.

> @user3749178 Curiosity. –  Ben Aston Apr 16 at 16:19

besides `var obj = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(fn)), fn);`, that depends on `ES6`, there is an `ES3` compatible approach that does wrap function objects into *callable* objects. Thus those objects are not callable anymore by the call operator `()`, but such objects do still expose two call methods `call` and `apply`.
Since this approach prevents on one hand function objects being invoked by `()` (methods/functions) or by the `new` operator (instantiation), on the other hand it still supports delegation (function based mixins/traits).

the gist hosted code of [`Function.toApplicator`](https://gist.github.com/petsel/a12e68bd7d5a4e9809e3)

Answer (score -2):

this isn't an elegant solution, the idea is to create the "enabled" attribute as a flag to know if the function is enabled:

```
var foo = function () { 
  if(!arguments.callee.enabled){
    throw "function disabled";
  }
  console.log("Hello");
}

foo.enabled = true;
foo();
foo.enabled = false;
foo();
```

Comment: this solution is not to my liking , for that reason I offer reward