# Can't set "apply" trap to Proxy object

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, proxy-classes

I created a Proxy object with an "apply" trap:

```js
var target = {},
    handler = { apply: () => 42 }
    proxy = new Proxy(target, handler);
proxy(); // TypeError: proxy is not a function
```

Therefore, the Proxy object should be callable. However, it doesn't work.

Why?

Comment: maybe related: [Making an object (non-)callable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29680473/1048572)

Answer (score 25):

According to the definition of the [[[Call]] internal method of Proxy objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getmethod) it should work:

> - Let *trap* be [GetMethod](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getmethod)(*handler*, `"apply"`).
> - Return [Call](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-call)(*trap*, *handler*, «*target*, *thisArgument*, [CreateArrayFromList](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createarrayfromlist)(*argumentsList*)»).

However, there is a problem: not all Proxy objects have the [[Call]] method:

> A Proxy exotic object only has a [[Call]] internal method if the
>   initial value of its [[ProxyTarget]] [internal slot](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) is an
>   object that has a [[Call]] internal method.

Therefore, the target must be a function object:

```js
var target = () => {},
    handler = { apply: () => 42 }
    proxy = new Proxy(target, handler);
proxy(); // 42
```

Note that I defined `target` using an arrow function in order to create a function object which is not a constructor function. This way the Proxy object can be called but not instantiated.

If you want to add a "construct" trap too, the target must have a [[Construct]] method, so define it with a function declaration or function expression.

Comment: "not all Proxy objects have the [[Call]] method" - this is the exact sentence that is missing in MDN docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I came here from Google searching for 'callable proxy'.
While the existing answer works, there is another alternative that may be 'cleaner' for some purposes:

```
class Callable extends Function {
  constructor() {
    super()    
    return new Proxy(this, {
      apply: (target, thisArg, args) => target._call(...args)
    })
  }
  
  _call(...args) {
    console.log(this, args)
  }
}
```

You can define all traps in proxy as usual.
All credits to [arccoza and his gist here](https://gist.github.com/arccoza/50fe61c8430fc97a463bf6b8960776ce).

Answer (score 0):

Using the info of the other answers I quickly cobbled together a generic utility.
You may add the call functionality to any existing object (not just functions) using the following utility `makeCallable`.

```js
type WrappedTarget<T extends object> = {
  (...args: any[]): any;
  originalTarget: T;
};

function createProxyHandlerForCallableAroundWrappedTarget<T extends object>(): ProxyHandler<WrappedTarget<T>> {
  return {
    apply(target: WrappedTarget<T>, thisArg: any, argArray: any[]): any {
      return Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argArray);
    },
    get(target: WrappedTarget<T>, p: string | symbol, receiver: any): any {
      if (p !== 'apply') {
        return Reflect.get(target.originalTarget, p, receiver);
      } else {
        return Reflect.get(target, p, receiver);
      }
    },
    set(target: WrappedTarget<T>, p: string | symbol, value: any, receiver: any): boolean {
      return Reflect.set(target.originalTarget, p, value, receiver);
    },
    construct(target: WrappedTarget<T>, argArray: any[], newTarget: any): object {
      return Reflect.construct(target.originalTarget as any, argArray, newTarget);
    },
    has(target: WrappedTarget<T>, p: string | symbol): boolean {
      return Reflect.has(target.originalTarget, p);
    },
    setPrototypeOf(target: WrappedTarget<T>, v: object | null): boolean {
      return Reflect.setPrototypeOf(target.originalTarget, v);
    },
    deleteProperty(target: WrappedTarget<T>, p: string | symbol): boolean {
      return Reflect.deleteProperty(target.originalTarget, p);
    },
    defineProperty(target: WrappedTarget<T>, property: string | symbol, attributes: PropertyDescriptor): boolean {
      return Reflect.defineProperty(target.originalTarget, property, attributes);
    },
    getPrototypeOf(target: WrappedTarget<T>): object | null {
      return Reflect.getPrototypeOf(target.originalTarget);
    },
    ownKeys(target: WrappedTarget<T>): ArrayLike<string | symbol> {
      return Reflect.ownKeys(target.originalTarget);
    },
    isExtensible(target: WrappedTarget<T>): boolean {
      return Reflect.isExtensible(target.originalTarget);
    },
    preventExtensions(target: WrappedTarget<T>): boolean {
      return Reflect.preventExtensions(target.originalTarget);
    },
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target: WrappedTarget<T>, p: string | symbol): PropertyDescriptor | undefined {
      return Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target.originalTarget, p);
    },
  };
}

export function makeCallable<T extends object, ApplyFn extends (this: T, ...args: any[]) => any>(
  target: T,
  onApply: ApplyFn
): T & {
  (...args: Parameters<ApplyFn>): ReturnType<ApplyFn>;
} {
  const wrappedTarget = function (...args: any[]) {
    return Reflect.apply(onApply, target, args);
  };
  (wrappedTarget as any).originalTarget = target;
  return new Proxy(wrappedTarget, createProxyHandlerForCallableAroundWrappedTarget()) as any;
}
```