# redefine function definition in javascript without reassigning it

Tags: javascript

Functions are callable objects in javascript so is it possible to redefine a function definition
?

so basically what I am trying to do is:

```
let a = function(){console.log('first');}
let b = a;
/**
 * alter definition of function 'a' something like:
 
  a.redefine(function(){console.log('second');});

 */
b();//should log 'second'
```

I looked up for javascript function documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) as well as [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) but couldn't find any reference on how/where functions definition are actually stored, even tried to inspect `a.prototype` as well as altering `a.prototype.constructor` but got nothing.

A workaround on this can be something like:

```js
let functionHolder={
    a:function(){console.log('first');}
}
let a = function(){functionHolder.a();}
let b = a;
functionHolder.a=function(){console.log('second');}
b();//would log 'second'
```

however my ultimate goal is to understand how functions actually work/stored in js and not a workaround just to achieve this.

Comment: No, this is not possible. Just like [it is not possible to make functions non-callable, or ordinary objects callable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29798915/1048572).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Once a function has been defined, its "function code" is immutable. The only way for a variable name which references a function to reference different "function code" would be to reassign the variable name to a new function.

Your

```
functionHolder.a=function(){console.log('second');}
```

is essentially the same thing - you're reassigning the function that `functionHolder.a` refers to.

In the specification, when you call a function, you invoke its internal method `[[Call]]`, which eventually leads you to
[OrdinaryCallEvaluateBody](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarycallevaluatebody), which does:

> Return the result of EvaluateBody of the parsed code that is F.[[ECMAScriptCode]] passing F and argumentsList as the arguments.

And the `ECMAScriptCode` internal property is not reassignable - it's only set in [FunctionInitialize](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-functioninitialize), when a new function is created (like when you do

```
<someIdentifier> = function(){console.log('second');}
```

)

Comment: @Cerbrus: I read the question as "is it possible to mutate a function object's code"; answering with a getter is like responding to "Do you know what time it is" with "I do". :P

Comment: @Cerbrus The getter idea is just a silly hack, and doesn't really address the fundamental issue: *however my ultimate goal is to understand how functions actully work/stored in js and not not a workaround just to achieve this.*

Comment: @Cerbrus The getter solution is just a better-hidden `functionHolder`...

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible by turning the `b` variable into a getter on the window object.

It's not pretty, but it works:

```js
let a = () => "foo";
console.log("a", a());

Object.defineProperty(window, 'b', {
  get() { return a; }
});

console.log("b", b());

a = () => "bar";
console.log("b", b());
```

`a` is a reference to a function. Call it a "pointer".
`b` is a copy of that pointer.

When you re-assign `a`, you're replacing the pointer. If another variable still points to the value behind the old pointer, that value still exists. That's why in your example, `b` didn't change: `b` was a pointer to the old function.

That getter is basically a function that's executed without explicitly having to call it, so it always gets the latest result of whatever the getter function does.

Comment: Ah setting a get property on another variable, tricky but still another workaround.