# Apply trap of Proxy

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

I realized that if I want to have "apply" trap in Proxy, the target of Proxy must be a function.  I need the target to be an object. I'm wondering if the target object can have some special "property" to be "callable" but not to be a function. Is there such way? Briefly for some reason I need "target instanceOf Function == false"

edit:
All ways how to make an object callable I found are based on extending Function class. Actually I don't need the target to be callable. All I want is that Proxy of my target can have "apply" trap. Is there any way without target instance of Function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you make an object 'callable'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335983/can-you-make-an-object-callable)

Comment: A workaround could be to use `new Proxy(new Function(), {...})` and to override everything (`get`, `set`, etc...) to point to the actual object. Not very neat though.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible in JavaScript for now