# Merging a function into an existing object

Tags: javascript

If one has an existing object `obj`:

```js
const obj = {
  i: 0,
  foo(){ 
    console.log(this.i) 
    this.i +=1
  }
}

obj.foo() // => 0
```

Is it possible to merge a function into it:

```
// the following function code should be added to `obj`
function obj(){
  this.foo()
}

// after the merge the following should both work:
obj.foo() // => 1
obj() // => 2
```

Comment: The problem isn't merging properties from a function (or any other object) to your original object, it's that objects can't be made callable. You would need some other type of data structure. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335983/can-you-make-an-object-callable).

Comment: You can assign all the properties of the object to the function. You’d then also need to bend over backwards a bit more to bind the function to itself so `this` works with just `obj()`. All that seems highly unorthodox though…

Comment: If anyone stumbles across this: here is the solution that ultimately worked for me: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAQgQwM7QLxVJOAzKOAIwCsBYAKAEsA7YCAJz2QGNp44oIAPemgE1SwEKdAG9KUKAAoAlAC4AbnCr9KAX0os4NVMEKkoWCRSlV5UAAwAaSVDwI5YqHanbdcADYQAdJ7gA5tLAABZUqD5Usi6mUthhEVRQANQYAIx2mhRZlMQkPg5wclAA9CVGAHxWlFo6evY0RvYArjQswFQ6LW1Odng0BY6yGlBownA1FADypBDtPujAAAoMcMBr4BBTeNL91gYksgDck-2DRdFllVAZFP3FVxhVAEyUZ4UP5U9QAMxvNJ9rgAWShAA

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the `obj` function is *merged* into the `obj` object if you want to call it standalone. However, you *could* use a bound function instead.

Besides: You cannot have a constant `obj` and a function `obj` that share the same name. I therefor changed the function name to `fn`:

```js
const obj = {
  i: 0,
  foo() {
    console.log(this.i);
    this.i += 1;
  }
};

function fn() {
  this.foo();
}



const bound = fn.bind(obj);



bound();
obj.foo();
bound();
```

**EDIT**

Now that I think of it, you don't need the `fn` function since you can use `const bound = obj.foo.bind(obj);` and achieve exactly the same:

```js
const obj = {
  i: 0,
  foo() {
    console.log(this.i);
    this.i += 1;
  }
};

const bound = obj.foo.bind(obj);

bound();
obj.foo();
bound();
```

Comment: Thank you.  This solution doesn't allow one to call `bound.foo()` - so one has two separate objects that need to be passed around, vs. a single integrated object.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge function to object using `Object.assign`. I changed `obj()` to `baz()` to make it more clear.

```
const obj = {
  i: 0,
  foo() {
    console.log(this.i);
    this.i += 1;
  }
};

function baz() {
  this.foo();
}

Object.assign(obj, { baz });
obj.foo() // => 0
obj.baz() // => 1
```

However when you call `baz()`, it will throw error because it doesn't understand the context `this` in baz(). So you need to call `baz()` with `obj` as the context

```
baz.call(obj); // => 2
```

Comment: thanks I did know that, I'm specifically looking to not do obj.baz(), but obj() directly.

Answer (score -1):

there are multiple ways to add property to an object like :

```
1.using dot notation, 
2.using bracket [ ] notation, 
3.using defineProperty(), 
4.using spread operator, 
5.using Object.assign()
```

```js
const obj = {
  i: 0,
  foo(){ 
    console.log(this.i) 
    this.i +=1
  }
}

const newObj = {...obj, obj(){console.log("ok")}}
newObj.obj()

obj['bar'] = function(){
    console.log("bar")
}

obj.bar()
```

Comment: The OP didn't want to know how add a new property to an existing object, he wants a function that, when called without context, behaves as if it is called in the context of the object.

Comment: can you edit the question? @David

Comment: Errr... why? The OP's description says what he wants to achieve, have a look into the second code block in the question.