# Handle function calls on a class in Node.JS

Tags: node.js

Assuming that you have a class

```
class MyClass {
    world() {
        console.log("hello world");
    }
}
```

I can run the method similar to the following:

```
var hello = new MyClass();
hello.world();
# outputs: hello world
```

Is there a way to handle direct function calls on an object? For example:

```
hello();
```

Returns: `TypeError: hello is not a function`.

Can I make this call a default function? For example, similar to [PHP's invoke function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) ...

Comment: Are you asking if you can have a static object?

Comment: You can't have callable objects in JS.

...Ok, you can, but it's really unadvisable, as it involves "fooling" the runtime. I can answer if you'd like, but I feel I should warn you _not to do it_.

Comment: @MikeCheel i'm looking for some type of proxy so that if I call `hello();` i really get `hello.default();` or `hello.invoke();`

Comment: @PedroCastilho only looking for standards-based approaches :) thanks anyway!

Comment: Functions ARE objects so technically you could work along those lines. What use case would this be for anyways?

Comment: OK, I found a different, standards-based way of doing this. Check my answer :)

Comment: Yeah I'm kinda interested in the use case as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can only make something callable in JavaScript if that thing is an object which, at some point, delegates to `Function.prototype`. Therefore, our class will need to `extend Function` or `extend` from a class which `extend`s `Function`. We also need to be able to access instance variables from our class object (in order to call `invoke()`), so it needs to be bound to itself. This binding can only happen in the constructor.

Since our class will inherit from `Function`, we need to call `super` before being able to use `this` . However, the `Function` constructor actually takes a code string, which we won't have, because we want to be able to set `invoke` later on. So we'll need to `extend Function` in a different class which will be the parent class to our class and which will do the work of setting the prototype of our dummy function (which we need in order to be able to call the returned object). Bringing all of this together, we get:

```js
class ExtensibleFunction extends Function { 
  constructor(f) {                          
    // our link to Function is what makes this callable,
    // however, we want to be able to access the methods from our class
    // so we need to set the prototype to our class's prototype.
    return Object.setPrototypeOf(f, new.target.prototype);
  }
}

class MyClass extends ExtensibleFunction {
  constructor() {
    // we build an ExtensibleFunction which accesses 
    // the late-bound invoke method
    super(function() { return this.invoke(); });
    return this.bind(this); // and bind our instance 
                            // so we have access to instance values.
  }

  invoke() {
    console.log("Hello, world!");
  }
}

x = new MyClass();
x(); //prints "Hello, world!"
```

I mostly adapted the techniques found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871299/how-to-extend-function-with-es6-classes) in order to do this.

An interesting aspect of using this technique is that you could name `MyClass` something like `Callable` and remove the `invoke` method - then any class which `extends Callable` would become callable as long as it had an `invoke()` method. In fact...

```js
class ExtensibleFunction extends Function { 
  constructor(f) {                          
    // our link to Function is what makes this callable,
    // however, we want to be able to access the methods from our class
    // so we need to set the prototype to our class's prototype.
    return Object.setPrototypeOf(f, new.target.prototype);
  }
}

class Callable extends ExtensibleFunction {
  constructor() {
    // we build an ExtensibleFunction which accesses 
    // the late-bound invoke method
    super(function() { return this.invoke(); });
    return this.bind(this); // and bind our instance 
                            // so we have access to instance values.
  }
}

class CallableHello extends Callable {
  invoke() {
    console.log("Hello, world!");
  }
}

class CallableBye extends Callable {
  invoke() {
    console.log("Goodbye cruel world!");
  }
}

x = new CallableHello();
x(); //prints "Hello, world!"

y = new CallableBye();
y(); //prints "Goodbye cruel world!"
```

(Of course, you could get the same effect by setting properties on function objects, but this is more consistent I guess)

Comment: In other words: a fancy way of instantiating a Function ;D

Comment: Indeed, but you gotta admit it looks nice :D

Comment: Absolutely, it almost looks like PHP! ;-)