# ES6 Class Extends Socket IO

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, ecmascript-6, es6-class

i'm working on a project and i need to extend

> socket.io-client

into a class, for now i can't get it to work, can somebody help ? :D

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export default class Websocket extends io {

  constructor(address) {
    super(address)
  }

  message() {

    alert('1')

  }

}

let socket = new Websocket();

socket.message();
```

If i try to call message method chrome outputs 'Uncaught TypeError: socket.message is not a function'

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `io` is a function, so you'll have to some fancy-shmancy constructor configuration if you want to continue down the route of extending a class onto it. Take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/36871498/1599663

Answer (score 3):

`io` is a factory rather than a constructor function and [returns an object created by the Manager constructor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client#api).

The error message now implies that the `constructor` function for `Websocket` returns the object returned by the `super` call, as distinct from the new object created when calling `Websocket` as a constructor. This is easily confirmed:

```js
var testObject = {};
function io() { return testObject;}
 
class Websocket extends io {

  constructor(address) {
    super(address)
  }

  message() {

    alert('1')

  }

}

let socket = new Websocket();
console.log( "socket same as testObject: " + (socket === testObject));
console.log( "Websocket.prototype.message: " +  Websocket.prototype.message);
```

Running the snippet shows `Websocket` returns the object returned by `super`, which, since it is not the object created by `new`, does not inherit methods from `Websocket.prototype` where the `message` method is sitting.

This calls for a rethink in design and perhaps further experimentation and learning about how JavaScript object prototyping really works. It also highlights the pitfalls of treating JavaScript as if it were just some yet-another class based language!