# Extending JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, function, class, prototype, extend

Is there a way to do the code below as a Class extending Function? if not is there a better way of doing it?  I do *not* want to use anything other than *standard vanilla JavaScript*

```
Function.prototype._data = new Map();

function TEMP (key) { return TEMP._data.get(key) }
TEMP.remove = function(id) { TEMP._data.delete(id) };
TEMP.reset = function() { TEMP._data.clear()};
TEMP.store = function(key, val) { TEMP._data.set(key, val) }
```

Currently this is what the class looks like:

```
class Temp extends Function {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this._data = new Map();
    }
    remove(key) { this._data.delete(key) }
    reset() { this._data.clear() }
    store(key, val) { this._data.set(key, val) }
};
```

I am new to Stack Overflow, and could not find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way is not to involve `Function.prototype`. Just do

```
function TEMP (key) { return TEMP._data.get(key) }
TEMP._data = new Map(); /*
^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
TEMP.remove = function(id) { TEMP._data.delete(id) };
TEMP.reset = function() { TEMP._data.clear()};
TEMP.store = function(key, val) { TEMP._data.set(key, val) }
```

Since there is only one `TEMP` with a single `Map` in your program, there's no reason to involve a `class` here.

---

If you need multiple instances, and insist on extending `Function` for that instead of using a simple factory, see [How to extend Function with ES6 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36871299/1048572).

Comment: thanks. I was hoping to make this function versatile, and useable in other projects as a library so to speak, but i gues this works.

Comment: To make a library from it, just wrap it in a `function makeTemp() {`…`return TEMP; }`.

Comment: thanks. but darn it, this so called short cut for a private map sucks... i cant do something like 
&quot;for (TEMP(0) in obj) { newObj[TEMP(0)] = obj[TEMP(0)]}&quot;
now i need to think of something else.

well, it has its uses...