# __proto__ of a function in the DOM in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-programming, prototype-chain

Why does `Element.__proto__ === Node` return true? Every function's `__proto__` value   is `function () {}`. How can I make a function that has for a `__proto__` value another function?

Answer (score 0):

> Every function's `__proto__` value is `function () {}`.

No, not every function inherits directly from `Function.prototype`.

> How can I make a function that has for a `__proto__` value another function?

Using `class extends …` is the most common pattern - the subclass constructor will inherit static properties directly from the parent class constructor (next to the prototype objects inheriting from each other). You can also do it by using [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) or by [inheriting from `Function`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36871299/1048572).

Comment: Can it be made without using classes (because they are new in Javascript, I suppose it can be made differently). Also, what's the point in making a function's __proto__ another function, not Function.prototype? What are some usages and examples using this?

Comment: @learningMath in classes they are used because then `super()` will point to the superclasses constructor and static properties will be inherited

Comment: Can this be done using this code: `Child.__proto__ = Object.create(Parent)`?

Comment: @LearningMath You can also do it by using [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) or by [inheriting from `Function`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36871299/1048572). Notice that `Object.create` isn't necessary, and also can't create functions. Also, `__proto__` is deprecated, don't use it.

Comment: @Bergi Can you give an example from the DOM functions where a function inherits methods from its `__proto__` function? Like `Node` and `Element` here, but I don't see any methods inherited.

Comment: @LearningMath `Element` inherits all the static properties of `Node` such as `Node.ELEMENT_NODE`

Comment: Thanks. But why are they shown on the Element.prototype object too in dev tools?

Comment: @LearningMath I guess because they *are* duplicated there because of IE compatibility afaik.

Comment: @Bergi Also, why is there written `Node` only on one static property from the right(which means it comes from Node) and not on the others? Does it mean that all the properties from that one, to the next where it says `EvenTarget` on the right come from Node?