# A default instance function call in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, oop

Okay I'm not sure what would you call this or what i should've used in title but what I'm trying to do is a class instance if called be one of the methods by default something like

```
class Something {
    method() {}
    another() {}
}

const instance = default(new Something(), "method");
instance(); // calls Something.prototype.method
instance.another(); // everything else should still exist
```

It would be something like cloning the whole prototype in a function object or something, i can't really think right now, Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to have happen here. Do you mean to define a `static` method that can be called like `Something.method()`?

Comment: You *can* do this a few ways now in JavaScript, but you shouldn’t. What makes it necessary here?

Comment: @tadman not a static method, i just wanna wrap the whole instance prototype inside a function that the function is also a piece of the class, something like callable class instance that by default calls one of the instance method i choose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot call an instance unless it is a function. There is no `default` function that makes anything callable. You would need to do

```
class Something {
    constructor() {
        return Object.setPrototypeOf(() => {
            // console.log("instance() was called")
        }, new.target.prototype);
    }
    method() {
        // console.log("instance.method() was called")
    }
    another() {}
}
```

to get a callable instance from `new Something`. And yes you could make that arrow function (that is currently empty) dispatch to `.method()`, but you could as well just place the behaviour right in there.

Comment: I thought you couldn't return anything in constructor? And yes i know i can't call an instance so what i was thinking is like const fn = new Class().fn; clonePrototype(Class, fn); so you still have all prototype methods in a function

Comment: It might help to note that `Object.setPrototypeOf()` returns the first parameter after modifying its `prototype`, since people who aren't familiar with this would probably not be able to guess that.

Comment: @FreeTNT Yes you still can return something from a constructor, and when it's an object it overrides the result value of the `new` expression

Comment: @FreeTNT that is not true. If you don't return anything, then the `constructor` implicitly returns `this`, but if a `return` exists in the constructor and its expression is an object, that will be returned instead.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I would hope people have to look up `Object.setPrototypeOf` and will also notice [the big red warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) I put there :-)

Comment: @Bergi you're the one that wrote that? o:

Comment: @PatrickRoberts [Not exactly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf$compare?to=510257&from=505441), but [I contributed to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf$compare?to=830567&from=776431)

Comment: Oh thanks guys, returning a Object.setPrototype(this.method, this.constructor.prototype); works to make the instance be callable and still being able to access other methods just what i needed.

Comment: @FreeTNT No, that doesn't work, that makes every instance *be* `Something.prototype.method`. If you use `return`, you need to create *new* objects on every constructor run. I'd suggest to use [this helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36871498/1048572) and write `class Something extends ExtensibleFunction { constructor() { super((...args) => this.method(...args)); } … }`.