# Can a predicate be an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Can a predicate be an object in JavaScript (as in C++)?

For example, is it possible to find the index of an element in an array (with arr.findIndex(pred)) with a predicate like this?

```
    class Predicate
    {
        constructor()
        {
            this.sum = 0;
        }

        evaluate(elem)
        {
            this.sum += elem;
            return sum > 25;
        }
    }

    const pred = new Predicate();

    const index = arr.findIndex(pred);
```

**EDIT1:** If no, what is the easiest way to find the index of an element that makes the sum of it and all the previous elements exceed 25?

Comment: Can a predicate be an object in JavaScript? -> NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a callback, this the function definition

```
arr.findIndex(callback(element[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])
```

You can provide your Predicate objects evaluate method. Like this

```
const index = arr.findIndex(pred.evaluate,pred);// pass pred as thisArg
```

Comment: You need to either bind the method or pass the instance as a `thisArg`

Comment: findIndex is being called on arr (Array), method is bound to the array. It runs perfectly fine.

Comment: my bad, i removed his logic and just tested the callback. Edited answer.Thank you for pointing out! http://jsfiddle.net/4ga3sLy9/3/

Answer (score 1):

Predicate has to be a function. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Syntax). But you could always create a function that returns another function.

```js
const runningSum = (sum, current = 0) => value => (current += value) > sum

const index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].findIndex(runningSum(25))

console.log(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an `evaluate` method (that would get invoked when an object gets called like a function) in JavaScript. However, functions themselves are objects and you [could even create them with `class` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36871299/1048572). It's not very useful though, in JS you would just write a closure to create a function with instance-specific values:

```
function predicate(max) {
    var sum = 0;
    return function(elem) {
        sum += elem;
        return sum > max;
    };
}

const pred = predicate(25);

const index = arr.findIndex(pred);
```