# Constructor chaining in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to concatenate strings by creating an object and passing down the constructor, so every time it is called it keeps the references of the previous one. I would like to achieve something like this:

```
foo = Chain("h")
bar = foo("e")("l")("l")("o")

foo.toString()          == "h"
bar.toString()          == "hello"
bar.ancestor.toString() == "hell"
```

What I have so far is a method chaining, when is rather similar but it is not quite what I want to accomplish here. I've been following the following documentation:

[Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

[Method binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Method_binding)

[Inheritance and prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

```js
function ChainParent() {
}
function Chain(letter) {
    this.letter = letter;
    this.ancestor = this.letter.substring(0, this.letter.length - 1);
}

Chain.prototype = Object.create(ChainParent.prototype) 
Chain.prototype.constructor = Chain;

Chain.prototype.create = function create(letter) {
    const letra = this.letter.concat(letter);
    return new this.constructor(letra)
}

Chain.prototype.toString = function() {
    console.log(this.letter);
}

const foo = new Chain("h");
const bar = foo.create("e").create("l").create("l").create("o");
foo.toString();
bar.toString();

bar.ancestor.toString(); //This won't work
```

Comment: What you want to achieve has nothing to do with constructor. Do you mean `foo = new Chain("h");`?

Comment: You start by saying you want `foo = Chain("h")`, but then you go on to say you want `foo = new Chain("h")`, ...etc. Which of the two is it? Can you make your question consistent in what it is asking for?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nvwaefq0/ without the `ancestor` property

Comment: What is the role of `ChainParent` here? It seems unrelated to your question...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible implementation of `chain` -

```js
const chain = (s = "") =>
  Object.assign
    ( next => chain(s + next)
    , { toString: _ => s }
    , { ancestor: _ => chain(s.slice(0, -1)) }
    )


const foo = chain("h")
const bar = foo("e")("l")("l")("o")

console.log(foo.toString())
console.log(bar.toString())
console.log(bar.ancestor().toString())
console.log(bar.ancestor().ancestor().toString())
```

```
h
hello
hell
hel
```

---

Per @IbrahimMahrir's comment, we can make an adjustment to `chain` to accommodate input strings of any length -

```js
function chain (s = "")
{ const loop = (s = []) =>
    Object.assign
      ( next => loop([ ...s, next ])
      , { toString: _ => s.join("") }
      , { ancestor: _ => loop(s.slice(0, -1)) }
      )
  return loop([s])
}

const foo = chain("hh")
const bar = foo("ee")("ll")("ll")("oo")

console.log(foo.toString())
console.log(bar.toString())
console.log(bar.ancestor().toString())
console.log(bar.ancestor().ancestor().toString())
```

```
hh
hheelllloo
hheellll
hheell
```

---

And here's another implementation of `chain` I thought about over lunch -

```js
const chain = (s = "", ...ancestor) =>
  Object.assign
    ( next => chain(next, s, ...ancestor)
    , { toString: _ => [...ancestor].reverse().join("") + s }
    , { ancestor: _ => chain(...ancestor) }
    )

const foo = chain("hh")
const bar = foo("ee")("ll")("ll")("oo")

console.log(foo.toString())
console.log(bar.toString())
console.log(bar.ancestor().toString())
console.log(bar.ancestor().ancestor().toString())
```

```
hh
hheelllloo
hheellll
hheell
```

Comment: The `ancestor` property doesn't work well if you pass strings that do not contain only one character

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks for the review. I made an edit with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [How to extend Function with ES6 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36871498/13175138) to make the class callable, so there's less boilerplate with the chaining.

In this example, each instance of the class keeps the the letter that it was given to start with, then merges them together using recursion in the `toString` function. So it acts as a linked list with a reference to the parent only.

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/36871498/13175138
class ExtensibleFunction extends Function {
  constructor(f) {
    return Object.setPrototypeOf(f, new.target.prototype);
  }
}

class Chain extends ExtensibleFunction {
  constructor(letter, chain = null) {
    super((letter) => new Chain(letter, this));
    this.ancestor = chain;
    this.letter = letter;
  }
  toString() {
    if (!this.ancestor) {
      return this.letter;
    }
    return this.ancestor.toString() + this.letter;
  }
}

const foo = new Chain('h');
const bar = foo('e')('l')('l')('o');
console.log(foo.toString());
console.log(bar.toString());

console.log(bar.ancestor.toString());

const foobar = new Chain('hel');
const barfoo = foobar('ll')('o');
console.log(foobar.toString());
console.log(barfoo.toString());

console.log(barfoo.ancestor.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just set the ancestor to the current instance (`this`).

Note that `toString` is a special method, as it gets called automatically when the JavaScript engine needs to convert an instance to a primitive value. So you should stick to the "interface" for it: it should return the string (not output it).

Here is an implementation of your final block using the modern `class` syntax. I allows `letter` to actually be a string with more than one character. The `ancestor` property will really return what the string is before the most recent extension:

```js
class Chain {
    constructor(letter, ancestor=null) {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.ancestor = ancestor;
    }
    create(letter) {
        return new Chain(this.letter + letter, this);
    }
    toString() {
        return this.letter;
    }
}

const foo = new Chain("h");
const bar = foo.create("e").create("l").create("l").create("o");
console.log(foo.toString());
console.log(bar.toString());
console.log(bar.ancestor.toString());
```

If you don't want a constructor -- so not `new` -- then the above translates to:

```js
function chain(letter, ancestor=null) {
    let that = {
        letter,
        ancestor,
        create(newLetter) {
            return chain(letter + newLetter, that);
        },
        toString() {
            return letter;
        }
    }
    return that;
}

const foo = chain("h");
const bar = foo.create("e").create("l").create("l").create("o");
console.log(foo.toString());
console.log(bar.toString());
console.log(bar.ancestor.toString());
```