# New function constructor that returns another function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this function in JavaScript:

```js
function test()
{
  this.list = {};
  return (id) =>
  {
    if (!(id in this.list))
      this.list[id] = {default: 123};

    return this.list[id]
  }
}

const blah = new test();
blah("ok").mykey = "ok";
console.log(blah("ok").mykey);
console.log(blah("ok"));
```

And I'm trying convert it into TypeScript format. I understand I'd have to use `class`, however how do I return a function from the class constructor?

I don't want have an additional property, `myfunc`, as a function `new test().myfunc("ok")`:

```js
interface simpleObject
{
  [key:string]: string|number|object;
}

class Test
{
  private list:simpleObject;

  public myfunc(id:string)
  {
    if (!(id in this.list))
      this.list[id] = {default: 123};

    return this.list[id] as simpleObject;
  }

  constructor()
  {
    this.list = {};
  }

}

const blah = new Test();
blah.myfunc("test").mykey = "ok";
console.log(blah.myfunc("test").mykey);
console.log(blah.myfunc("test"))
```

[On TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgM7ALYAcA2EDyARgFYQJgBQA3hcsgNoDWEAngFyphSgDmAumzRdeAHxABXDIWgiA9iTJgA3BQC+FBDjipUySJ2q1kWbgDc4kZDmCcOmXAQXkVdLOMLWEyDCxjiQCAAUwAAmHMIgPACURjR0dMAwyIEAhMEhyKB6ABY2AHTWnFEx8fFguagFNmD0oXzIALzIVCEQ8OI4YIIAjABMAMyqKkZ0UBBg4lAgOfmFNXXI2mj2eESkzkbqdAiyIJxQ4uSyUIElzSMzlXONzUObahQau5zIHnDZNyAQAO56EJynFRvbJ5Hx+AKBABE+jAkKioJYzBYN0hskYkJUOz2sjwBVkPECwIR4KC0P+sPhPiRUUxzxxEDxBKJYP8pJhcKiQA)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use `new` on something that returns a function? Just call the function without `new`.

You can achieve that by keeping your state in closures instead of using `this`;

```
function test() {
  const list: {[id: string]: any} = {};
  return (id: string) =>  {
    if (!(id in list)) {
      list[id] = {default: 123};
    }
    return list[id]
  }
}

const blah = test();
```

See [Live Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgJQCgDeuiiECGiANjBgFyL4DaMAJnRgE4xgDmAunQEMwATwC+iALz1RAbiKJ2KKCHZJMLNlE49skgHzzCxYjGCJMAQnXNEXStSjY8x41QxNmvSfWYpgAkAooOgBGACYAZllceWJFZVV7dxZeeVFcdNxSMHIAIwoBAAtvVAwcOXyizAAiOABrauwAOgBbYTqUYW9ahpkgA)

I think this is what you should use. Having said that, the ability to specify what a constructor returns [is not yet available](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27594) but could be in the future.

I could suggest a workaround (from the linked issue above) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871299/how-to-extend-function-with-es6-classes) but I don't see why you'd want to use that for your case since what I suggested is simpler and there is no need for classes here.

Comment: I guess I don't really have to, I'm just used to use `this`. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The constructor of a class will return the instance of said class, and that is the intended behaviour. Your use case doesn't really necessitate usage of a class. You can still have your function and use `this` inside. To tell TypeScript what type `this` is, you can use a reserved parameter:

```
type ReturnedFunction = (id: string) => string | number | object;
type TestFunction = () => ReturnedFunction;

function test(this: TestFunction): ReturnedFunction {
  // same code as before
}
```