# Replace/modify `new Function` in JavaScript [to use `TrustedScript`]

Tags: javascript, polyfills, trusted-types

### The objective

I've been working on a polyfill of sorts for the [Trusted Types API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Trusted_Types_API). Part of what Trusted Types does is update handling of "injection sinks" such as `Element.prototype.innerHTML` and `new Function()` to accept `TrustedHTML` and `TrustedScript` instead of strings. The polyfill to create the new classes is already done, and I'm adding the additional script to replace injection sink methods.

**Note:** I'm doing this following a spec and recreating the behavior in Chromium browsers. I think that the added security justifies changing the built-in methods if not already supported. It's separate from the polyfill itself in a separate script (harden.js).

#### An Example

```
const sanitizer = new Sanitizer();

const policy = trustedTypes.createPolicy('default', {
  // This is used for `el.innerHTML`, `iframe.srcdoc`, and a few others
  createHTML: input => sanitizer.sanitizeFor('div', input).innerHTML,

  // This is used for `eval()`, `new Function()`, `script.text`, etc
  createScript: () => trustedTypes.emptyScript,

  // This is mainly for setting `script.src`/`script.setAttribute('src', src)`
  createScriptURL: input => /* Something to check that the URL is allowed */
});

document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = '<button onclick="alert(document.cookie)">Btn</button>';
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML; // '<button>Btn</button>'
eval('alert(location.href)'); // Does nothing... Same as `eval('')`
const func = new Function('alert(location.href)'); // This is what I am wanting to change
func(); // This should do nothing, similar to `eval()`
fetch instanceof Function; // This should remain true
```

This all works without issue, but I can't seem to update `new Function()` in a way that supports/requires `TrustedScript` while still preserving `fetch instanceof Function`.

### Failed Ideas

Both of these use a `createScript()` method that's not particularly important here. It checks for support, checks the type of input (string or `TrustedScript`), and tries `trustedTypes.defaultPolicy.createScript(input)` as needed.

```
// This doesn't work and is never even called

const func = globalThis.Function.prototype.constructor;

globalThis.Function.prototype.constructor = function Function(...args) {
    if (args.length === 0) {
        return func.call(this);
    } else {
        const funcBody = createScript(args.pop());
        return func.apply(this, [...args, funcBody.toString()]);
    }
};
```

... or

```
// This fails `fetch instanceof Function`

const NativeFunction = globalThis.Function;

globalThis.Function = class Function extends NativeFunction {
  constructor(...args) {
    if (args.length === 0) {
      super();
    } else {
      const funcBody = createScript(args.pop());
      super(...args, funcBody.toString());
    }
  }
};
```

### To Summarize

I'm trying to replace/update `new Function()` to support/require `TrustedScript` in a way that does not break `fetch instanceof Function`. Everything else was doable since it required just updating certain methods / setters, but `new Function()` is a constructor and I don't know how to change it without changing `Function` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `instanceof` operator checks whether the lhs has the `.prototype` of th rhs in its prototype chain. So when you replace `Function`, you'll need to ensure that `Function.prototype` stays the same. You can do that using

```
const NativeFunction = globalThis.Function;

globalThis.Function = function Function(...args) {
    if (args.length === 0) {
        return NativeFunction.call(this);
    } else {
        const funcBody = createScript(args.pop());
        return NativeFunction.call(this, ...args, funcBody.toString());
    }
};
globalThis.Function.prototype = NativeFunction.prototype;
NativeFunction.prototype.constructor = globalThis.Function;
```

---

Btw, using `NativeFunction.call` is a) slightly insecure, since it could be overwritten to gain access to the `NativeFunction`, and b) slightly incorrect since it'll break [subclassing `Function`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36871299/1048572). You could either just call `NativeFunction(...args, funcBody.toString());` (given the `thisArg` isn't used anyway) or better use `Reflect.construct(NativeFunction, [...args, funcBody.toString()], new.target)` (assuming you actually use a save non-overwritable reference to [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct)).

And then there's other ways to obtain a reference to the `NativeFunction` that you'll need to prohibit it you want to make this really secure, ranging from `Object.getPrototypeOf(AsyncFunction)`/`Object.getPrototypeOf(GeneratorFunction)` to using iframes to access a fresh realm. This will evolve into [SES](https://github.com/endojs/endo/tree/master/packages/ses) if you really mean it…

Comment: Edit: That works, and I've gone with `NativeFunction()` instead of `NativeFunction.call()`.

I chose to not rely on `Reflect` though. At least pending a review of compatibility, which is especially important in a polyfill.

At least in Firefox, `AsyncFunction` and `GeneratorFunction` do not exist as constructors, and the spec doesn't mention them at all, so I'll not be worrying about them for now.

And as far as SES... I suppose you could see this as a spec-following trade-off aiming for simplicity and best load times. I'm kinda at a race against any malicious scripts injected...

Comment: As such, I'm also not too invested in what can be done via `<iframe>`. `TrustedTypes` already adds `TrustedScriptURL` for `src` and `TrustedHTML` for `srcdoc`, so I think that threat is sufficiently mitigated. Any `<iframe>` will have to have been already trusted.

And I'm not sure if you're referring to/aware of `Realms` in a JS proposal. That'll add a whole other world of problems since each Realm is "vanilla" and unaffected by such modifications.

Comment: `AsyncFunction` and `GeneratorFunction` do exist (see the spec!), they're just not exposed as globals, but can easily be accessed from `(async()=>{}).constructor` and `(function*(){}).constructor`. If you're trying to safeguard `Function`, you'll also need to safeguard them! (And `AsyncGeneratorFunction` and possibly more…)